# How to sum rows from a child table grouped by a column in parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have two tables in MySQL:

**Parent**:

```
parent {
  id: int,
  name: string,
  group: string,
}
```

**Child**:

```
child {
  id: int,
  parent_id: int,
  value: int,
  value_date: date
}
```

Here is some sample data:

**parent**:

```
id | name | group
1 | A | G1
2 | B | G2
3 | C | G3
4 | D | G2
5 | E | G3
6 | F | G3
```

**child**:

```
id | parent_id | value | value_date
1 | 1 | 50 | 2018-09-17
2 | 2 | 10 | 2018-09-17
3 | 4 | 20 | 2018-09-17
4 | 2 | 60 | 2018-09-18
5 | 3 | 20 | 2018-09-17
6 | 5 | 30 | 2018-09-17
7 | 6 | 50 | 2018-09-17
8 | 5 | 20 | 2018-09-18
9 | 1 | 30 | 2018-09-18
10 | 3 | 30 | 2018-09-18
```

I want to find the sum of the  values in `value` column of child table, grouped by the `group` of parent table and the `value_date` column of the child table. How to do that in single query?

Here is what I want in result:

```
group | sum(value) | value_date
G1 | 50 | 2018-09-17
G1 | 30 | 2018-09-18
G2 | 30 | 2018-09-17
G2 | 60 | 2018-09-18
G3 | 100 | 2018-09-17
G3 | 50 | 2018-09-18
```

Basically, it is a grouping of the child values based on parent group and child value dates.

Right now I am doing this:

First getting all the distinct Groups like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group FROM parent;
```

This will give me following values: ('G1', 'G2', 'G3')

And then I call the below query once for each distinct group value from the above result from my Java Code:

```
SELECT SUM(value), value_date FROM child WHERE parent_id IN (SELECT id FROM parent WHERE group = ?) group by value_date;
```

**Java**:

```
List<String> groups = getGroups();    

for (String group : groups) {
    Map<String, Integer> dateValueMap = getValue(group);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do hope your column name isn't `group` as it is a SQL term and reserved word

```
SELECT
    parent.`group`
  , child.value_date
  , SUM(child.value)
FROM parent
INNER JOIN child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
GROUP BY
    parent.`group`
  , child.value_date
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-G

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out, I have changed the name to parent_group!
and thanks for the answer! Its so simple I can't believe I couldn't figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  parent.group,
  child.value_date,
  SUM(child.value)
FROM
  parent
INNER JOIN
  child
    ON child.parent_id = parent.id
GROUP BY
  parent.group,
  child.value_date
```